# JQuery loop through multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array. I want to remove the class "list" when it is in one of the div in my array. But it is possible that there is more than just one div with this class on my site.

So I tried to resolve that with two for-loops but I get it didn't work.

```js
const $lists = [
                $('.first'),
                $('.third')
            ];

var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < $lists.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < $lists[i].length; j++){
        $lists[i][j].find(.list).removeClass(list);
    }
}
```

```css
.list {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="first">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="second">
   <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="third">
   <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also tried it with CSS and :not[]. But that didn't work too.

.

```
 .list:not(.first)  {
     border: 3px solid red; }
```

Comment: classnames should be enclosed in quotes. `.find(".list").removeClass("list");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the selected divs by to one by applying [`jQuery.merge()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/), find all items that contains the `.list` class, and remove it:

And if you want to remove it just from first and third:

```js
var $lists = [
    $('.first'),
    $('.third')
];

$($.merge.apply([], $lists)).find('.list').removeClass('list');
```

```css
.list {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="second">
   <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="third">
   <ul class="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".second").not(".first, .third").addClass("list")
});
```

```css
.list {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="second">
   <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="third">
   <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>fooooo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```